# Laravel : php artisan route:list is displaying html tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, routes

I was having this error in my browser

> install:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I really don't know how to fix this so maybe I just trace the routes. so I used the

```
php artisan route:list
```

and I got these results: 20 times of this html snippet
[image]

then all the routes.

And I am using this [LCRM](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3oObO_L7QAhWJTbwKHbYpD_YQFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodecanyon.net%2Fitem%2Flcrm-next-generation-crm-web-application%2F14506615&usg=AFQjCNFSNeg8SLPx2wkiSciNeEOH0a7t5Q&sig2=lZ_AuSjiGTlykXfxHUDY5w&bvm=bv.139782543,d.dGc)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting html code because you have a syntax error or a controller is missing. Laravel shows that error because your debug is set to false.

Try edit your file **app/config/app.php** file  and if you have a **app/config/local/app.php** edit the debug line there too.

Near the top yo have a 'debug' line, set to True and you will see de issue and you can fix from there.